# How to scale UIImage in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AllMyFiles-1 (dragged).tiff"];
cell.imageView.image = image1;

cell.textLabel.text = self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

And this is is what it looks like:
[tableview with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cuia.png)

And I want the UIImage to be a bit smaller much like this:
[tableview with smaller image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZuyD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options to solve that...

1) You can put transparency in your image,
getting something like that: [image centered with transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkYu.png)

2) You can draw your custom cells prototype on your StoryBoard or Xib file

3) You can resize your image programmatically:

Add this method on your class or a extension of UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *) reziseImage:(UIImage*) image withSize:(CGSize) newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

And call it on your method:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AllMyFiles-1 (dragged).tiff"];
cell.imageView.image = image1;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(25, 25);
image1 = [self reziseImage:image1 withSize:newSize];
cell.imageView.image = image1;

cell.textLabel.text = self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```